# Using OpenSSH between Windows 10 machine & a Linux board

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, openssh

When I run the below commands from Windows, the shell script `a.sh` on my Linux board works very well. The Linux shell script `a.sh` is in directory `/home/root/proj`.

```
ssh root@192.168.1.145
root@board:~# cd /home/root/proj
root@board:~/proj# ./a.sh arg1
```

However, if I try running the command:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.145 "cd /home/root/proj; a.sh arg1"
```

The script fails executing when it tries to run the executable file within the script. It says it cannot find a shared library object file & therefore cannot load it; although the file exists.

Any tips or clues will be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: It's trying to run a command which name would be `cd`, then a space, then `/home/root/proj;./a.sh`, then another space, finally `arg1`.

Comment: @uprego No it's not. It does exactly what OP intended.

Comment: @uprego That change by OP actually fixed the problem the question was about in the first place. That makes the question moot. I'm reverting your reversal.

Comment: Ah, understood. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the interactive shell you are executing

```
./a.sh arg1
```

While on your `ssh` command-line you are executing:

```
a.sh arg1
```

That's not the same command.

Do not omit the `./` part:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.145 "cd /home/root/proj; ./a.sh arg1"
```

Comment: Martin Thx for your suggestions. It seems that just doing ssh root@192.168.1.145 cd /home/root/proj;./a.sh arg1 works ok. Also, adding the -t option to it works ok. Now I'm going to try to run the command inside bash on Windows.